# x label in matplotlib using Latex wrapper: the space characther disappears

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I want to set some part of the text of the x-axis bold and some other part normal font (not bold). I tried to use the Latex wrapper of matplotlib (which works) but the space character string `xlabel bold` (between xlabel and bold) disappears. How can I fix the problem?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathbf{xlabel bold}$ - ' + r'xlable not bold')
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\bf{xlabel bold}$ - ' + 'xlable not bold')

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\bf{xlabel \ bold}$ - ' + 'xlable not bold')
```

Or you can use this:

```
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\bf{xlabel}$ $\bf{bold}$ - ' + 'xlable not bold')
```

Alternatively you can use a simple function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def bold_text(text):
    new_text = text.replace(' ', r'}$ $\bf{')
    new_text = r'$\bf{'+ new_text + r'}$'
    return new_text

new_text = bold_text('this is some bold text')
ax.set_xlabel(new_text + ' - ' + 'xlable not bold')
plt.show()
```

For even more options you can go to:
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Spacing_in_math_mode

Comment: and by the way. This works fine. But let's say I have more than 2 strings separated by space character. The code gets clunky quickly. There is no cleaner workaround?

Comment: I have edited my answer. There a many options